# Is there an option to hide/disable the "volume" display in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

It seems that when the object is rotated in *Edit Mode* the "volume" representation will sometimes change, appear and disappear and various angles and distances.  I figure there is an option somewhere that I haven't discovered but, in the meantime, does anyone know if it's possible to turn the "volume" display off?  It's not bad but it can be distracting.

thanks

[image: volume representation]

Comment: AFAIK, there is no "volume" display. As already mentioned by ideasman42, I think what you are seeing is the problem mentioned in [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh). this is caused by [Z fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) (also as already mentioned by ideasman42)

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is related to the display camera's clipping distance. Clipping distance is basically the distance the camera can view.

You can change the settings around in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: You're right that the clipping distance is influencing it.  I need to work with it more to understand what it's really doing.  Still seems more confusing than not.  Thanks for the direction to look

Comment: @askinner432 if this answer has solved your problem, remember to [mark it as "accepted"](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) :)