# Where can the viewport clipping parameters be changed?

Tags: 3d-view, customization

Zooming in to inspect texture details in 3D view clips some closer faces like shown in the image. It's not the camera view so changing camera settings doesn't help.

Where can the distance to the clipping plane be adjusted?

[image]

Comment: It does affect Orthographic view still to this day.

Comment: Is there a way to set this value for default, so it would be the same for every workspace and blender start file?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's in the 3D View area's **Properties** <kbd>N</kbd> menu > **View** tab:

[image: Blender 2.8 screenshot]

It doesn't affect *Orthographic* view, where there's no view distance.

How to set the the view port clip parameters per Python script is described in [an answer to the question "Setting camera clip end via Python"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38613/2169).

**Older Blender 2.7:**

[image: 1a]

Comment: I've found that if I turn clipping all the way down (so I can get as close as possible) produces weird graphical glitches where polygons look like they are displaced or missing.

Comment: @DavidS. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1387/599

Comment: I'm using Blender 2.75 and adjusting the end value *is* fixing this issue in orthographic view, for me at least.

Comment: What are the disadvantages to having a large clipping plane?

Comment: @AaronFranke The depth-buffer (also called z-buffer) loses accuracy when you have a large range of potential values across different magnitudes. This can result in what is called "z-fighting", where the depth coherency of the render is compromised because the machine can't accurately calculate the true depth of individual pixels in the scene. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)

Comment: Where is this menu in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 5):

As I searched a lot for this pane, here where I found it on Blender 2.8:

1. Click on the small arrow on the top right
   [image]
2. Then a pane shall open. Click here on view.
   [image]
3. There are the view clipping settings. Observe the view horizon and change the end value.
   [image]
4. No the horizon is more far away.
   [image]