# How do I get imported objects to show in view? (.wrl files)

Tags: 3d-view, import

I'm new to Blender.  I have imported a large (file size 259 mb) file into Blender (2.7.1).  The files are all listed and selectable from the Scene tab. However, I can't see the objects.  I feel like they are perhaps too large (virtual physical size) and therefore out of view.  The file is a Solid Works 2014 export. Is there a way to change the field of view or another thought on getting them to show?

Comment: When you select the objects, what are the object dimensions in the [Properties Panel](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Panels) -> Dimensions? I mean the shelf opened with N in 3D View.

Comment: A quick way to find your object is to press A to select all and then Numpad "." (view selected) It is possible that even though your object is there you can't see it because of the clip distance. See:  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: Ok some of this is starting to make sense. First of all pressing A doesn't selects everything including camera.  But I was able to deselect them.  Home and pressing 0 a few times did reveal, sort of, that the objects are there.  However, in the N 3D view it just shows 1.0 for XYZ when all selected. Now for individual items that came in it shows crazy big numbers for dimensions, like 2010x 773y, 2010z. for this particular object.  There are a lot of objects that make up the actual assembly.  How do I resize those dimensions for all objects and with in aspect ratio?

Comment: If I could "check" mark comments for answered I would on several.  First of all the Clipping path did allow me to "see" the object.  The imported files were so large I had to zoom way out an set my clip end path very high.  So that solved the original question.  However, the real issue were the object sizes.  I could "Scale" the objects to get smaller of course once I could see them.  I however did that with the transform tool.  @user2859 I never really understood the Dimensions in N panel.  I get they were too big, but can that be altered to resize?

Comment: @archJones well dimensions are just to check the bounding box of an object. You can also scale objects with it, but i would not recommend it, because its hard to manage values to uniformly scale them (better use the scale values for that). Pressing 'A' selects all if nothing is selected or deselects all if something is selected. So with all objects selected you can type "S .001 Enter" e.g. to scale to 1/1000. This is non destructive as long as you don't apply scale. Those comments are not intended as answers but just to determine what is going on.

Comment: Thank you @user2859.  Those questions helped answer the question.  Objects were too large, so the clipping path was not allowing me to see the objects. Viewing the dimensions N 3D view showed the bounding box was giant. Managing the clipping path allowed me to see the objects.  I did rescale all of the objects with transformation to get the objects as they should be.

Comment: @archJones I suggest you write up an answer to your own question for others to learn from your experience.

Answer (score 1):

- Select all objects in the outliner or other means. Press the home key ... the one NOT on the numeric keypad. (there are two home keys on many full size keyboards)
- After that is successful. Consider press numeric keypad 0 a couple of times to switch bebtween

  User View and Camera View.
- Press Control Alt (Numpad) 0 to align the camera view with the user view.

Comment: No need to select the objects I think, home fits all visible objects (i.e. objects in the current layer which are not hidden) into the view regardless of the selection.