# Importing into Blender a Collada export (.dae file) from Sketchup

Tags: import, collada

I am trying to import a Sketchup model (`.skp` file) into Blender and then later on into Unity.

First, I did the default Collada export, but upon importing the `.dae` file into Blender, I got nothing.

I, then, followed the instructions on this webpage: [Import SketchUp ".skp" files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/import-sketchup-skp-files) but the result was just an empty Blender scene...

Something that might be useful to know is that in my first attempt to use Collada export, there was a folder craeted (during the export process) with 3 materials in it. It basically means my model uses some material (brick texture, metal surface, etc...) which might be the reason for the failure of export/import processes.

Has anyone run into such a problem before? Is there a work around for this kind of work that deals with multi-layer multi-material 3D models craeted in SketchUp?

Thanks,

p.s. I would be happy to send my file over to someone who believes they could analyze it and see perhaps what the problem might be...

Comment: Have you checked other layers? you could have imported the .dae into a different layer than your were viewing.

Comment: Also check your clip point, sometimes objects show up in blender either too big or too tiny... see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16652/how-do-i-get-imported-objects-to-show-in-view-wrl-files and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed