# Blender cycles dof viewport problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view, depth-of-field

When I set dof in the viewport it looks ok but my rendering just doesn't show it in the same way. Just there is no dof. My scene has multiple layers in compositor. What have I missed?
Thanks.

Comment: it might not be related but mostly when I've run into render/viewport differences it's because of the [viewport's](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed) clip planes being at different distances from the [camera's](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance).

Comment: I guess I got how to solve this after exploring goole with correct words. I think that each layer must have its own defocus node in the compositor. I'm doing a quick test here right now. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: On cycles you can try using the camera's Depth of field and focus control andnot use a defocus mode at all

Comment: yes, my first trying was in this way but it results no dof, despite right camera settings (I guess). My test using defocus node didn't work also.
it's so strange. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. In the viewport everything is ok, the scene has a nice dof.

Comment: I'll do a new test. This time using just one layer. Let's see what happens.
Thank you guys.

Comment: Please edit tour question an add images of your camera setting's dof settings, node configuration or, even better, post your blend file.

Comment: Thank you mates, jozxyqk, cegaton. I made a big mistake. I thought that new feature automatically change the camera values with the values of f-stop in the viewport.
My sincerest apologies for your time.