# Fixing disconnected vertex

Tags: mesh

I have a planes mesh of which I thought it was connected.
But when I drag the one edge around, I can see that it is not connected.

[image]

I tried just everything I could image, but I have not been able to fix it.

Can anybody show me how that could be done?

I have uploaded my blender file here:

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36943

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *edit mode* <kbd>RMB</kbd> the vertex labeled 1 then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd> the 2nd vertex.

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> (merge) select *At last*.

Comment: Thank you! Since you have seen my project. Does it not happen for you that part of the model and grid disappears when you zoom in this far?

Comment: @tmighty Yes it happend to me also, it is the camera clipping , See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed on how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

You also could use the snapping tool:

[image]

Choose 'Vertex Snap' and then grab the vertex close to the other vertex. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to activate the snapping.

Then the vertices should snap together. When you have snapped all your vertices you want to Merge, select everything by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>. Then press <kbd>W</kbd> an choose 'Remove Doubles'.

This is a much faster way to do it if you have to snap multiple vertices.

Comment: This works even better with automatic merge

Comment: oh thank you!! never heard about that. (I never have to use Remove Doubles again !! :) !!)