# Why blender rendering objects to block/cut each other? And how to avoid it?

Tags: rendering

It looks like one object projected and blocked/cut another.
[image]
It gets worse with more distance between objects.
[image]
How to avoid this mess?

Comment: In addition to @DrRiisTab answer, sometimes it may be caused by the bad **viewport clipping** settings. Please see related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the camera end clipping.

As you see it 
[image: here] the left cube is renderer with a proper camera clipping while the right one is rendered with a too low end clipping

As you see it
[image: here]
you can change the camera clipping in the properties menu while the camera is selected.

**Try to increase the camera end clipping**