# Select seams easy and fast way?

Tags: uv, selection-tools

Is there a way to select seams the easy and fast way?

I had to subdivide this part with 20 so it would bend well, but now its all black so its impossible to seam. I already zoomed in with DEL (numpad), but that doesnt make it easier to reach tiny parts. Also whenever i zoom in, the object just disappears, so im searching a way that or automatically selects the seams for me or a way where it select a few connecting points at once.

Pls explain step by step what to do, cause im just a beginner. Thanks for all the help here!

[image]

Comment: I wasnt asking why it is black or why it is zoomed in. I just stated it to explain the situation more clear. Also i would like more help on how to use smart UV project since i also stated in just a beginner and have no idea how to get there. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Yes*, but working with such a high-poly mesh isn't advisable for a number of reasons.

Instead, consider using a [Subsurf modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html). This allows you to work on the mesh in a low-poly state while still getting the nice smooth curves offered by a high-poly mesh:

[image]

That said, if you can manage to select one edge with a seam, then you can press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *> Seam* to select all other seam edges. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> for *Border Zoom* and, if needed, a [reduced minimum viewport clipping distance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4946/599) can help immensely with such a task:

[image]

Comment: thanks for this. I use blender 2.7 and i choose subdivision surface modifier, but im a bit clueless what to do with it. I selected the object and am now in edit mode.

Comment: @Fur Adding the modifier is just about all you need to do. It'll perform subdivision on your object as you edit it. If you want, you can have the "edit cage" (the initial low poly mesh you are directly editing) be mapped to the surface of the high-poly mesh by selecting the triangle icon near the top of the modifier (as in the gif above). To be honest though, I rarely work with that enabled. Have a look at [the manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html) and see if it helps answer your question

Comment: The manual is very hard for a beginner to follow. It didnt help me much with my question. Im still stuck after i adding the modifier, cause it just doesnt do much. I dont see any difference. So i just tried to select an edge, click shift+G (u said ctrl+G but i figured out it was shift+G) and then everything gets selected. The object is still black as well..

Comment: @Fur Ah yes, it's Shift+G, my mistake. The modifier is meant to be used on a low-ish poly model. If you already have lots of polys, then you won't notice the effects much.

Comment: SHIFT+G still works(2.8), amazingly useful.Thanks.