# Automatically select texture seams?

Tags: texturing, uv

i am making a game, and i have some issues with a model i am making. THe model looks normal in blender, but when i am in my game, it is all messed up where the texture seams are. I need to edge split the texture seams. but i don't know where they are in blender, I am hoping for a way to easily auto select the uv texture seams. here are some screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not clear why there's a need to split mesh on seams, afaik game engine does that by itself. However you can select all seams by using Shift+G menu (not automatically of course, one seam edge has to be selected). See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65097/select-seams-easy-and-fast-way

Comment: I have a feeling i will need to update my blender for this, but thank you :)