# Understand how to make EXTREMELY large objects if i should?

Tags: units

So intend to make a space colony ship for a VR game I'm messing around with and I'm wondering if i should even be doing it this way.

The ships length measurement is going to be 18000 meters obvious this is massive I'm not too experienced in Blender but i found how to increase the size of the grid.

Unfortunately no matter what I try 18000 goes far beyond it and when i try to zoom out the screen goes weird.

What is the correct way of doing this or is Blender not the right place to do something this large.

I have seen videos on youtube comparing sizes of ships but i cant figure out how you can see everything in that

Comment: Scale in 3D models is relative, 18000 is just a number, the absolute size is irrelevant, what you have to worry about is the relationship between size and level of detail. It may be feasible, look into *Viewport Clipping* settings and adjust them to match your scene for the display issues. Also consider dividing your ship into a modular design composed of blocks and reusable assets so you can break it apart into several working files and work on them separately

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: thank you for that link and yea i could split it up how would i go about connecting the image thats going to cover the ship if i split it

Comment: How would this VR game work? is it a pre-rendered or point-and-click style image based game, or will it be using a full 3D environment rendered in real time? What game engine will you be using? This is probably a question best asked at the game engine forum/site, not necessarily Blender related.

Comment: it will be htc vive using unity unity uses meters ( i think) and The original ship size was going to be 18k meters but i wasnt going to have the  actual item in game be that long was to make another item thats the ship but smaller. But now that i think about it when you make a scene you dont need to make it the exact size just make it look that large. But and now that you bring that up im coming up with ways to make it so i dont have to make the entire ship render

Answer (score 1):

After comments and talking to people I realized that i shouldnt actually make something that large. when im making a scene just make it look larger than it is and when its in game make it so they dont realize isnt completely made