# How to set up a camera in a pit?

Tags: camera

I am setting up a first-person-shooting scene, where I want to place a camera inside a pit on the ground.

Ideally, at a proper height from the pit bottom, the camera is expected to capture the pit wall in half of its view and outside world in the other half such that the camera peeks at the world from *inside* the pit.

However, I'm having a hard time achieving this, although I've physically placed the camera *inside* the pit.

By tuning focal length and near clipping (values of which are unconstrained and free to vary in my case), I get something like this

[image]

The pit appears *in front of* the camera.

How can I actually make the camera view be half pit wall and half the world, just as what our eyes see if we are squatting inside the pit?

---

My minimal working example Blender file:

[image]

Comment: See this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is that your pit is ridiculously small, increasing its size fixes the issue, is there any reason to make it so small?

Comment: @tacofisher Unfortunately I am not free to change the size of the pit, as I am given an elevation map and asked to make a "topographically accurate" scene...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. It's related to viewport, but I am asking about camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set your near clipping distance to 0

[image]

You should also consider changing the ***Unit Scale*** so that your objects are of reasonable relative size.  I increased it from 0.001 to 5:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change the scale for the scene, so that you are working in mm?

Comment: @cegaton - Yes, you can change the unit scale. Maybe he changed it accidentally.  Good call