# What do i need to change in order to view my DXF

Tags: 3d-view

I am exporting my drawing from autocad into blender. The drawing is in 1:1. When i import the DXF into blender i get this cut off view of my drawing. How can i fix this?

Heres how this appears http://recordit.co/VrQ6eHOpNO

Comment: The camera has a field limit. See [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/camera.html)

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed