# Imported OBJ doesn't seem to render correct in object mode

Tags: rendering, objects, import

i'm very new to Blender so keep in mind that this could completely be my fault ;).

[image]

What am I doing wrong, i can't seem to fix this problem. To me it looks like it is a rendering problem, and not a model issue.

I'm using blender on a macbook pro 2016, blender version 2.79b.

Comment: Just a viewport *clipping* issue: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: hm, i vote to reopen because in that question cliping is because of zooming to close to the object, but  in this question because of scale. Answer should be different.

Comment: Even if it is different by some subtle detail, this is still a very poorly researched question and it is extremely frequently asked. It should not be reopened in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it is like a clipping issue here:

[Where can the viewport clipping parameters be changed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed)

But, for me it's more about scale. Normaly, objects fits in default clipping settings, but your is so huge! So I suggest you this:

- Select all the staff, (it's looks like it is already selected) when press <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>,<kbd>.</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>to make it 100 times smaller (or even more if you want).
- When apply scale by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> **Scale**

Unfortunately import OBJ does not have scale option