# Newly Created Objects Not Appearing In Any Mode

Tags: mesh

I am very new to Blender and am just now experiencing this issue. Whenever I create a new object in any layer, it registers as either an orange selection point or the spawn cross (as seen in the screenshot). How can I fix this? [image]

Comment: Try pressing "numpad dot" (or in the View menu, View Selection), this will force the view to zoom out (or in) to show the selected object.

Comment: My computer doesn't have a number pad, so I have Emulate Numpad selected in my Input settings. Still not sure what you mean by <kbd> , tried holding these keys at the same time and also tried pressing . ; neither is working.

Comment: Already tried View Selection in the View Menu, only the crosshairs show up, not even the orange selection circle. My current screenshot reflects my view after View Selection.

Comment: Your object is quite large, make sure the View Clipping can handle it (Properties panel / View / Clip). It would help if you could upload the .blend.

Comment: I don't see any orange dot in the viewport in the screenshot above. Crosshairs you mention appears to be 3D cursor which in Blender is used to define location of newly created object. From what is seen on the screenshot mesh *should* be visible and it's really there which is shown in Outliner. Then check [clipping settings for camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4946/1245), and try to uncheck Render Only in the Properties shelf > Display rollout (right of the viewport)