# How to make blender render a further distance

Tags: rendering, clipping

When I render my project the building towards the top right is cut off and I don't know why. If someone can explain a way to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Increase the *Clip End* property of the camera in it's Lens properties. Or press <kbd>N</kbd> and change it under View tab. [More info here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed).

[image]