# Blender 2.80 displaying weird artifacts in Layout mode but not in Modeling mode

Tags: modeling

Im new to Blender. I was trying one of the tutorials on youtube when suddenly the objects in viewport started displaying weird artifacts. These artifacts are not visible in modeling or sculpting mode. I have included the image with artifacts. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image: artifacts in layout mode]

Comment: Hello :). Looks like a too wide clipping distance. This thread could help: [Where can the viewport clipping parameters be changed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4946/78972)

Comment: Yes your right!!! I changed my clipping angle too 0.01cm. Anything lower than that and it starts to fudge. Thank you.