# render area around the camera

Tags: rendering

I have been working on a project and when I started using the camera I noticed its view did not go very far, any way of increasing this? [image]

here is what I mean, you can see the view is curving around the Minecraft blocks and not showing the scene.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can the viewport clipping parameters be changed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed)

Comment: no it did not work I even tried

Comment: :( thanks for trying tho

Comment: The same settings can be found in the camera properties.

Comment: ok so the camera properties clipping worked but the view clipping didn't but thanks anyway for the answer