# Volume material disappear when I move further

Tags: materials, volumetrics

I was trying the volume material and when I move my view further, volume disappear.

My camera will set further than this so this is a problem to me, I googled about this issue but I couldn't find answer.

Is there a way to display volume material from further away? About 5000m ~ 10000m.

close
[image: close]

far
[image: far]

fog node
[image: fog node]

I am using 2.91 and this is my file:
[My file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uDa2_kSIfW7Ycu1aJbcJ00AB_PCGGDPZ/view?usp=sharing)

THX!

Edit:

volume has its own distance clip.

[image]

Comment: im not sure but this **could** be a viewport problem and the volumetric can bee visible in render , try doing a single frame render from far away where volume not visible in viewport

Comment: read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: Thx!  There is a bar speical for volume, I attach in edit.