# object renders and behaves different

Tags: rendering

[image]

[image]

This is the image using the EEVEE render mode. The render was fine and all and don't know what happened but after rendering sometime later the object has converted to this.

I closed the file and reopened it but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hello :). That's just viewport clipping distance issue. Your model isn't broken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can the viewport clipping parameters be changed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed)

Comment: It does look like inverted normals, to be sure of this disable backface culling in material properties, if the issue is fixed then invert your normals.

Comment: @JachymMichal that is not right: clipping would look like somebody cut off the front or back of the model, not like it’s inside out.

Comment: @Yvain I agree, or alpha blend. That could also cause this. Turn alpha blend off and see if that fixes.

Comment: @Zargul This isn't a result of high clipping *distance*, but of high clipping *range*. The floating point accuracy has it's limits, which can cause this :).

Comment: Btw - the fastest way to solve this is usually switching to *Orthographic mode* (Numpad 5)

Comment: @JachymMichal not this kind of error. Look at that other question you linked. It looks like part of the face got chopped off on an even plane. That’s not what’s happening with this model.