# strange edges look in Viewport

Tags: 3d-view, shaders

I got strange "triangles" all over my scene in viewport. How to fix it?
[image]

more here:
[link to YouTube](https://youtu.be/O0CSKpMyUXc)

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It's a camera clipping problem. Your clip start and end are too far apart. I can't find an exact duplicate but you should find the options there https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4947/86891 make sure there is less than 10^7 or 10^8 difference between start and end

Comment: I sometimes experience this as well. What helps most of the time is to change _Clip Start_ and _End_ in the View options (as @Gorgious said). Sometimes I also hit Numpad "." to center on selected objects or Shift + C to _Center Cursor and Frame All_.

Comment: @moonboots the file is here https://pasteall.org/blend/7ce3b5e6ba01406dbbb84a881c1e45ed

Comment: @Jacek Słoma it looks like Gorgious is right