# Why is my image disappearing?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, image, video

I'm trying to create a 3d map with a moving line showing the path. All done as per the Youtube tutorial from "Imagiscope Tech". Everything up until the import into Blender works perfect. As per the video, I've imported the sequence from Earth Studio as well as the .jason file. It plays perfect, but as soon as I roll the mouse wheel to change perspective, it disappears and I have no idea where it is. What am I doing wrong.

Running Blender 2.83.0. was running 2.93.0, but it did the same thing, so thought if I used the same version as in the tutorial, it might work.

[Youtube video for reference here:](https://youtu.be/URkMK2QJUwE)

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you for the reply.
Here is a drive link to all the files I'm using:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Y03iepm6wwferbn7NAVwP-kfJpd_NXR6?usp=sharing

Comment: Your camera is far from the scene center, you can move it or at least increase the scene clipping in the N panel (on the top right of your 3D view, display with N) > View > Increase the Clip End value

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: Moonboots, Brockmann, Chris... Thank you, yes, this helped a lot. Now I can figure out the rest of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Moonboots already commented, increase the clip end of your camera until you "see" something. Or just move the camera nearer to your object.

Everything outside this clip range will be hidden by Blender.

[image]

by the way, you can even animate the clipping values, which gives a pretty nice effect:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the image Chris, came in very handy