New blender update auto hides objects
I just upgraded to 4.1 and I noticed a new feature that makes blender hard to use for my work. I make jewelry and blender is auto hiding objects, I would think it is so that you can see the selected object better. But for me I can't see the intersection point up close which is essential for me. You can also select the object that hides but that prevents me from being able to move the originally selected object. Additionally I also noticed in edit mode when I zoom it switches the viewport shading from solid to wireframe. Again I bet this feature may be nice for larger work but for jewelry design it can be pretty frustrating. Is there a way to turn off this new features?
Simple blend file of two objects, when you zoom into the smaller object the larger objects hides 







Hello and welcome, I have never seen a feature like that, are you sure is not a bug or a boolean modifier? Also, The switch one does appear like a bug or a keyboard shortcut mess

Agreed! I've never seen that or any information about it being changed for version 4.1. Blender 4.1.1 is out now with some bug fixes but i don't think any of the corrected bugs involve your problem.

There's no such thing as an auto-hiding feature. It sound like either a misuse of something, or a bug. Sharing your file with one of the hidden object would help understand what is going on.

It definitely could be a bug. I was able to recreate this issue with just two objects in the file no modifiers. the object that is bigger hides when you zoom in. The object is also not hidden as if you  were to hit Control H

How can I add a file to this? also curious if this happens to anyone else when you zoom in

From your comment description, you might be referring to clipping distance see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

I have the clipping start at 0.001mm. Is it possible to add a video to a comment? I just took a quick video showing it but not sure how to upload

No. You can't add images or videos to a comment. However you can edit your question and add images or an animated Gif into that. You can also share a Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Just a thought: Have you checked that your machine's graphics drivers are up to date?

Just uploaded a gif of a simple file with two mesh objects no modifiers. Will upload file to the blend-exchange.com

I already tested your file and it's working correctly. It could be your machine, a bug in your version or gpu not up to date. If you are using Blender from a different source that the website, try the one on the official site or the portable version.

In the viewport > Sidebar > View tab > View panel:

Your clipping starts at 0.1mm and ends at 5km. A good rule of thumb is to keep the clipping start/end within a six figures magnitude.
If you want to be able to see objects as close as 0.1 mm to your view. Then your end clipping distance shouldn't go beyond that magnitude:
$0.1mm\times10^{6}=100000mm$
Interestingly, your render camera's clipping values are in that range already. But for anyone else, don't forget to also pay attention to your camera's clipping:


Thank you! I adjusted my end clipping value to 100000 and that fixed this issue
