# How do I increase the render distance?

Tags: rendering, camera

I have created a simple model here
[image]

When rendering it the end of it is cut off
[image]

How can I get the camera to render a longer distance?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The camera can only see the geometry that is within a range defined by the [clipping distance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/camera.html?highlight=clipping#clipping).

Anything that that closer of further away from that distance range will be ignored.

With the camera object selected, increase its **End** clipping distance in *Properties > Camera settings > Lens*:

For 2.79 and earlier versions

[image: 1a]

For 2.8

[image]

To visualize the camera clip distance select the camera and enable **Display** > **Limits**.

[image]

For 2.8 enable Viewport Display> Limits

[image]

Comment: Read also: [Why does part of my model disappear when I zoom in on it in the 3D Viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport)