# 3D 360 VR Image seems off

Tags: oculus, vr

Im working on an 3d archiviz project but ran into some issus.
I tried to render a 3d 360 image to view it on the ocuclus quest.
The bathroom is finished (Blender 2.9) and I set the camera with [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/quick-guide-how-to-render-in-virtual-reality-360-stereoscopic-format-with-blender-2-8/1194137) settings.
Als soon as I import it into 3D vista and view it on the Quest the scale seems off, especially on the bottom and top.
It doesnt look like the real scale. [Here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AGwHvErhQ6c%5FWj0&id=50D43B99A86189AE%2136860&cid=50D43B99A86189AE) is the blend and some rendered images.
Hope someone could tell me how to fix this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never actually done VR stuff before, but I would think that you would need quite a bit more than two spherical images to get the stereoscopic effect to look right since your head can be rotated to any orientation. With only two cameras, the views would only be correctly aligned when looking straight ahead or straight back.

Comment: Linking a couple of q&a that might helve you solve it. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52231/rendering-a-stereoscopic-image-in-blender-2-77 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46132/any-way-to-create-a-360-stereoscopic-video-for-playback-in-vr