# Blender renders blank image

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I've got a very large model. I can see it fine in object view, but it keeps coming up blank when I try to render it. Here it is in 3D view (through the camera):

[image]

...and here it is after it's rendered:

[image]

Everything's enabled in outliner, and all of the layers are checked for rendering under Properties/Render Layers.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm at a loss. Any suggestions?

Comment: In render tab-> Post processing -> Uncheck Sequencer option.

Comment: Nope, that was already unchecked :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)

Comment: Try pressing Pos1 when pointing your mouse over render window. This will zoom the render window to the maximum visible size.
But since your rendertime is not even one second for this big scene, I guess it's quite another problem. Consider uploading your [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! I just set the camera's clipping too high, apparently!