# Cycles Smoke Simulation Section Invisible in Camera and Render

Tags: 3d-view, camera, smoke-simulation

If I go into rendered view, I can see the whole smoke object:
[image: Smoke in Viewport]

But if I am in camera view or I try to render, part of the smoke is invisible:
[image: Smoke in Camera]

I am using blender version 2.79
Is this A known bug? Is there an easy way to fix it?
My .blend file is available here:
[image]

Comment: Most likely clipping distance for the camera is not enough. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance

Comment: Either that or you have an object with a holdout material... or you messed with render layers. However, I'm not getting any smoke from your file at all.

Comment: The file I included didn't have the smoke sim attached. So you would need to re-simulate it. But changing the clipping distance fixed it for me.