# My Viewport looks like im having a graphics bug

Tags: camera

My viewport is looking weird..

Problem:

[image]

See below for Solution

Comment: Please put solutions into an answer .

Comment: oh i  thought the 2 day wait time also is for answering your own question. Not only for accepting it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)

Comment: Just because both deals with clipping doesnt mean it's a duplicate.. The reason for asking is completely different.

Comment: @cegaton https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Select your camera and go into the properties. The near-clipping of the camera is to small.

[image]