# Puzzled with clipping mystery -- can't control border in meaningful way

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

I hope a kind person can explain me what is going on in this file:
[blend-file with objects](https://we.tl/t-rF7ZNHbJsS) (seven days from now)

(01) 
In my perception "Clipping-settings" for Camera determines the distance of visible space in Blender viewport, yet trying to enter altered values produce no change. The objects are simply devoured by a blenderish void despite larger numbers. What is going on?

(02)
Don't know if theseproblems are interconnected, but why is the values different for the same camera i different view ports? Please see attached.

Kind regards, Mikael

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are not controlling camera clipping values, those are viewport clipping parameters and are not associated with the selected camera object. Camera settings are in the properties window

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance

Comment: Very useful and utterly clarifying: Thanks alot! :)

https://pasteboard.co/HG6DtYs.png

I have obviously and all time confused the clipping-zones for viewports and the actual camera. The latter specs. are found under Properties --> Camera
Kind regards, Mikael