# Blender gets buggy after several hours?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

I'm new to Blender and 3D modeling in general.
I've been working on a model for about 5 hours. Just as I was preparing to render and save a picture of it, parts of the model started disappearing. They're not deleted, and there's a light source, they just don't show up. At first it was only like this when I looked through the camera using Ctrl-0, but now nothing it working like it used to when I started. Oh and I'm using Cycles Render.

What could be the problem?[image: Pieces Disappear]
[image: Pieces Disappear 2]
[image: Pieces Disappear 3]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Changing the camera settings worked for the render, which is awesome! But in "regular" view there is still this big gray shadow that won't let me see all of the model at once... it wasn't there when I began the project, only after I started adding color and render options. See what I mean in the 'user ortho' views?

Comment: That is because you set the two clipping distances too far apart. These are very frequent questions and have all been answered before many times. If you search you will find the answers to your questions.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I did try to search, but when you're a beginner, you don't know enough about the error to know what you're looking for. All I know is that Blender seemed to stop working correctly for no reason. I altered the clipping distances, but the "gray shadow" still remains... I will do a search about clipping distances now. Thanks.