# Help! Most of my project doesn't show, but still renders

Tags: objects

Please see the attached video, I've got no clue what happened.
https://youtu.be/Y7li1KvwnL4

Comment: Seems like you are in a clipping mode. Press ALT-B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be due to the clipping border as Serge mentioned above, you can click on View > Clipping border or use the ALT + B hotkey

Answer (score 0):

Might be your rendering range. I've found how rendering range can ruin an amazing image.

Maybe see this,
[How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)
 might answer your question.