# Render my 3dmax scene in blender

Tags: rendering, camera

I'm having problems with my rendering. I did an interior design scene in 3dmax with the furniture, and exported (.obj) to blender. But when I go to the camera view it turns gray, and if I move the camera the objects deform.

How can I make the camera work correctly?

[image]

This is my scene in blender:

[image]

I put the camera

[image]

I hit show the camera

[image]

And if I move the camera the object deforms.

Comment: There are many reasons why you could experience what you are experiencing. Is the camera pointing at a wall or some other object that blocks the view? Is the [clip distance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201) for the camera set at a very short distance? Are there more than one cameras in the scene and you are using the wrong one?

Comment: Please read carefully through these links and see if any of the many proposed solutions work for you: [Render result completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/) and [Why does my object now show up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490) If none of those solutions work for you please  edit your question and add more information.