# Why my renders don't render to the bottom?

Tags: rendering

I'm rendering some products and when pressing F12 I'm getting 90% of the image rendered, there is a gap at the botton. It gets outputed when saving image as PNG.

[image]

**DOWNLOAD SCENE:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-HbS0Q7hUOtK9dkXayaZ4VGkTxzwPWWp/view?usp=sharing

Examples of output (a & b have the problem, cups.png was rendered with other configuration):

[image]

This is my active camera, the only one:

[image]

Another perspective of the camera:

[image]

**UPDATE 1**:

Incresed `Clipping End` from 1000 to 2000 with same result.

[image]

Moving the camera a little bit to the top yields this result:

[image]

Comment: Check the clip distance **Start** for the camera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance/5202#5202)

Comment: @cegaton please, see attached scene for download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two overlapping object a plane and the curved backdrop. No two objects can be in the same place or else they cause what is called Z-fighting.
See those zebra-like things on top of the plane and the curved backdrop for the scene?

[image]

Get rid of the plane.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unwanted advise: if you are just starting with blender, create your own scene step by step and learn from it, instead of dealing with the errors of someone else that created the scene you are using. Instead of deconstructing and needing help on every step you will learn quicker and with a more solid footing.

Comment: thank you. As you notice, I'm a new user to Blender but I've used Cinema4D when I was at University. Now I'm doing some adds for my own company (small startup) and Blender is such a great tool for this. I'll take your advice. And thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check to see if your Camera Render ... has a transparent background.

Choose
Shading Alpha Sky

Not
Shading Alpha Transparent.

Comment: Please. see attached scene file.