# Environment(world) texture engulfing meshes in Camera view

Tags: camera, world

Left panel shows how i want the cam view to be and the right panel shows the cam view.I am new to blender.The environment hdr seem to engulf meshes in camera view.
I guess it is something to do with the world settings.Please help.[image]

Comment: I think what you are seeing is actually clipping based on the camera view start/end. See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5201/935)

Comment: Yeah thanks.Clipping was the issue. Increasing the end value solved it.