# Rotating view causes large objects in model to get distorted

Tags: 3d-view

When my model gets pretty large and I try to rotate it, only certain view angles work. In other angles, it looks like it is breaking up or distorting. I am not trying to render and I'm not using a camera. I am using version 2.79. I tried updating to 2.81, and it did the same thing so I went back to 2.79 to get this project done. I have attached a couple pictures. One shows what it should look like and the next shows what the distorted image looks like. Help much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance/5202#5202

Comment: That's clipping. 3D View > N, Properties region > View tab, Adjust the near clip nearer, and the far clip nearer, too,  if everything still fits the depth. (This comment is possibly a duplicate)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the end from 1m to 10m and the problem went away.