# Viewport for large distances in scene

Tags: 3d-view

I'm rendering space-craft ( ~1000m radius ) orbiting Jupiter (150 000 km radius )
I have trouble setting up viewport so that I can edit the scene conveniently. There is some **fog** and **clip-plane**.

- The clip-plane can be set in "Camara > clip start, clip end" 
  [How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)
- but still there is the **fog** :-(

I found only this about the issue. I cannot believe it is not possible, because I expect this problem must be very common