# object disappears on material mode not clipping problem

Tags: objects

Hey all I've encountered a problem on material mode my object is not fully showing I've checked my clipping
details and played with it a bit but the object is still not showing could use some help please

Material mode :

[image]

Rendered mode :

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)

Comment: no, my problem is not on render mode that is fine it's on material mode I can't see my model and the clipping end is set for a 1000