# object disappears when looking through the camera view

Tags: rendering, objects, export, camera, color

I am taking a youtube course about making a medieval well but have some problems. Made the well, added environment texture, emphasized the camera and lights.

Before I clicked the “0” button on the Numpad this was what I saw in the viewport:

[image]

When I clicked the “0” button on the Numpad this happened:

[image]
[image]

I am new in blender, made some projects so far but had not met a problem like this before. I want when go in camera mode to see the well and the blue background, then to render the image.
Please tell me how may I fix this!

---

Comment: It does not help! The result is the same as what you see on image #2 in my question. Thanks :)!

Comment: I did it. Still does not work. Thanks again :)!

Comment: Is this what you need? [how do I increase the camera distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)

Comment: I fixed it at last. My object was very big. Scaled it down and rendered image.