# Circle in top right hand corner of render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

What is this circle in the top right hand corner of the rendered image? i have attached an image of the render[image] i really cant see what it could be.

Comment: You mean the dark one? Where you're seeing off the side of your cove?

Comment: Yes that one thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make the backdrop larger so that it fills the frame.

Or if you are clipping an existing object, then adjust the clip distance for the camera.

[How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)