# Zooming from <10000 meters to 10cm

Tags: 3d-view, scale

I imported a quite huge model from a GIS with the size of ~10000x10000 metres. Now I want to scale it down to ~10cm. But when I do it, I can´t zoom to my model. At some point the Background raster disapears and I can´t find it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the clip distance, both for the viewport and the camera,
to have a clip distance that uses a much closer range.

See:

[How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the number pad period key? The number pad period key will zoom to the selected item if your mouse pointer is within the 3D viewpoint. You can select your item by pressing the "a" key to select all or find it in the outliner.