# Why can I see through my objects?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

When you fly through your Blender 3D world, you can fly through things. However, sometimes I fly through objects, and before I even get close to them, the objects start cutting off(visually). See image:

[image]

How can I stop Blender from doing this? Or at least make it do so, when I get closer to the object?

There are some camera angles that I can't get because Blender cuts away the object in my view/cam

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is caused by the **View Clip** setting in N panel (If you look through the camera, it is controlled by the camera clipping that locates in its own **Object Data** panel).

[image]

To avoid it, either set start clip to a relatively small value (0.1 by default), or switch to **Ortho** view (3D view only).

Comment: cameras also have this property

Comment: @Vader That's right.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the `Start` lower than the default has some weird effect on which lines get hidden in shaded mode :-/ It's a little annoying, but not a big deal. I'm mostly just surprised that it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: @Matt That sounds strange indeed. I noticed that too. Not sure if it is kinda real bug. Thanks for reminding. :) will try discussing with devs.

Comment: @Matt See [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1387/599). It's apparently not fixable and affects all openGL applications. So note that there are good reasons for *not* setting these to the largest values possible where it can be helped.

Comment: @gandalf3 That's very informative! It seems something like so.

Answer (score 7):

What happens in your extreme situation you have very small objects and moved the camera quit close to them:

[image]

I think if you would look the scene from outside it is more clear what happens:

[image]

The View Clipping Start (as explained by Leon Cheung's answer) value is the distance from the center of the camera to the near clipping plane (yellow).

[image]

<sup>[Image source: Wikipedia Viewing_frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum)</sup>