# How do i show the whole object in the camera view before i render?

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

I am trying to render an animation, I have set up the camera in the right position but not all of the object is showing in the camera view, like its in shadow. how can i fix this?

Thanks[image]

Comment: This is due to the *clipping* being set too small. Note that there are separate clipping settings for the camera and the viewport, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7185/599

Answer (score 1):

Increase the clipping end of the camera from camera setting.
[image: Clipping]