# Why does part of my model disappear when I zoom in on it in the 3D Viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm having an odd issue - When I try to zoom in on a detail using my MMB, the "camera" in the 3D view seems to be cutting off the exterior surface of my object and showing me the inside instead. I'd expect this behavior, but only when I was much more zoomed in.  If I zoom out a bit (one click on the scroll wheel) then I can see the exterior as I intend.

Is there any way to adjust this behavior?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance and https://blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view

Answer (score 73):

### **Clipping in the 3D Viewport:**

It sounds like you have your camera's Start Clipping Distance set too high in the 3D Viewport Properties. Clipping distances define the range (in distance units) within which objects are visible. If your distances are set incorrectly, your view gets "clipped" when you cross the clipping threshold, as you describe.

To change the 3D Viewport clipping settings:

1. Zoom in/out until your objects get clipped
2. Go Properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) -> View tab

[image]

3. Set the `Clip Start` distance lower or the `End` to higher until you see the objects you are interested

**NOTE:** These settings **only effect display when NOT in Camera view**)

[image]

You can read more about [clipping in the 3D Viewport here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/3d_view.html).

### Camera Clipping Settings

Just so you know, there is also the option to adjust the clipping range of a camera. This effects the scene when viewed through the camera, such as in Camera View or when rendering. To change these properties:

Select camera -> Object Properties window -> Camera tab -> Lens section -> adjust the Clipping Start and End values

[image]

To visualize the camera clip distance, select the camera and enable **Display** > **Limits**.

[image]

You can read more about [camera clipping distance here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cameras.html#lens).

Comment: Thom,thanks for the response.  The problem is not with the actual camera perspective.  It's with the user perspective.  Is there a way to adjust the clipping distance for that?  Nevermind...I found it.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what might be the use of this feature?

Comment: @PeterGašperan I am not familiar with it, but this is what I found on google: [Purpose of camera clipping](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&client=safari&hl=en-us&ei=TpZxWLWULeawjwS_46PwDg&q=camera+clipping+purpose&oq=camera+clipping+purp&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.1.33i160k1l2.3397.6514.0.8303.6.6.0.1.1.0.144.683.0j5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..1.5.589...0j0j0i20k1.vrhssrHbsbA)

Comment: @PeterGašperan according to blender: "A large clipping range will allow you to see both near and far objects, but reduces the depth precision resulting in artifacts.

In some cases, a very large range may cause operations that depend on the depth buffer to become unreliable although this depends on the graphics card and drivers."

Comment: The first link on this question is broken

Comment: @ThomBlairIII thank you. In my case, I'm following the donut tutorial in Blender 3.0 (*I'm using 2.78c*) - and I believe in my case this issue is due to the change of the unit measurements. I've changed to centimeters, so, the clipping start to end was like: `start: 10 cm` - `end: 1 km`. Changed to: `start: 1 cm` solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The issue you're having has to do with the "clip point".

Blender sets limits past which objects will not get displayed.

There is a start (close) and end (far) clip point.
To change press <kbd>N</kbd> and look for the clip settings in the *View* rollout. Change the start clip to a lower number.

[image: ClippingViewAdjust]

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open up this panel, go to view and change the *Clip Start* value accordingly to the size of your object.

[image: The panel]