# Active camera have a short view distance,how do I increase it?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, camera

For some reason when I render or turn into active camera mode the mesh obj disappear as I move farther. I need help on how to increase that view range.[image]

[image]

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8555#8555

Comment: You need to change the *clipping end*  in the *Camera settings* (Select camera > properties editor > camera icon (object data) > lens) here is a [screenshot](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/70987). The setting you changed in your screenshot only affects the viewport outside of the camera.

Answer (score 11):

Select the camera, then increase the Clipping `End` value in the Camera's properties panel.

[image]

Comment: That did not work,the camera still can only see a little distance.

Comment: Are you saying it had no effect?

Comment: yeah it had no effect on it,the view range didn't even shift

Comment: That's odd. Haven't seen that before, are you in GLSL Shading or the normal Multitexture ( Properties/Shading )? Did you try setting the View camera setting too ( Properties/View/Clip End )?