# How to make the measuring grid larger?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, units, dimensions

When starting the blender, there is always a cube on the floor. The floor is actually a grid. My question is how to make this grid bigger so that we can measure big stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about this grid in perspective view...

[image: That grid on the floor.]

Since your goal is to measure things relative to a grid, you can use orthographic view to do that, which makes it easier to construct geometry. Here's how it looks like:

[image: Top ortho.]

This is the same cube in orthographic projection viewed from above. It is easy to get there. Assuming you are still using the default key mapping (you havn't changed the keyboard settings) you can get to orthographic by pressing **5 on the numpad** and then pressing **7 on the numpad** for top view, and **3 or 1 on numpad** for other directions.

So you insert a plane, which is 2x2 initially, as you can see.

[image]

Now I scale it to 50x50...

[image]

That just go big. Now I get to orthographic view with **numpad 5**...

[image]

And now I switch to top view...

[image]

As you can see now, the grid is now spread in all directions infinitely. You can zoom out to see that...

This is the same 50x50 plane.

[image]

What you might complain about is that you can't see the grid *inside* the plane? Well, for that just switch to wireframe (*by pressing **z**). Here's how that looks like...

[image]

That's one way of getting what you want.

Comment: Thanks very for you help. It is really appreciate if you can help me out of this question. In the first pic in your post, there are 16 * 16 grids under the cube, how could we get, say, 32 * 32 grids? In my case, I added a plain, and scaled its size out to 50 * 50, so that I want more grids to measure it......

Comment: Like I said, you can use the orthographic view to measure your plain. Let me show you...

Comment: I just made an edit to give you an example. Happy modelling!

Comment: How do you actually insert a plane?

Comment: OP asked "...how to make this grid bigger so that we can measure big stuff?". That can be easily done, but this answer doesn't explain how to do that. Maybe it's just because this answer is very old and the grid scale is a new feature? Currently, there is a much better/easier way.

Answer (score 20):

You can change the size of the grid to accommodate your needs, or you can change the scale of the whole scene.

## To change the scale of the grid in the 3D view.

For 2.8X Open the overlay controls.

[image]

And change the scale and number of subdivisions.

For 2.7X
Press <kbd>N</kbd> to reveal the properties shelf.

On the **Display** section you can change the grid floor number of lines and scale.
The left side of the screen will show info on the scale of the units used.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Pepribal/Ref/3DView/Sidebars/Properties/Display):

> ***Lines** defines the number of lines that will make the "floor grid" up. If N is the number defined, there will be a total amount of N/2 lines at each side of X and Y axes. For odd values of N, the amount of lines will be rounded down.*
>
> ***Scale** defines the distance between grid lines, either in the "floor grid" and the infinite grid.*
>
> ***Subdivisions** defines the amount of lines into which the infinite grid should be subdivided. Level of subdivision depends on zoom, in predefined orthographic views.*

[image]

## To change the scale used for the scene:

Other way to deal with large (or very small) objects is changing the scale on Properties->Scene->Units->Scale

[image]

[image]

Note that changing the scale for the scene in the Units Section will affect the size of the grid, but changing the size of the grid in the 3d viewport will not change the scene's scale.

Besides the floor grid, Blender has some built in measuring tools that you might find useful.

For 2.8, in **Edit mode** (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), open the **Overlays** section and you can choose to enable the boxes for Edge Length, Edge Angle, Face Area or Face Angle.

[image]

For 2.7X, in **Edit mode** (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), enable the numeric panel (Kbd>N) and look for the **Mesh Display** section, to enable display of edge and face info of an object.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When dealing with very large or very small objects they might seem to disappear from view due to the clip distance on the viewport. If that happens you might need to change the start and end clip values.

See this question: [Why does part of my model disappear when I zoom in on it in the 3D Viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8554#8554)

Comment: perfect!  a 2.8 version question!  Thanks, just what i needed!