# How to change the snapping increment in different units?

Tags: customization, transforms, snapping

I would like to know how to change the increments used for snapping transforms.  This would be useful in a number of situations but my problem now is that when I change the units it does not scale the snapping increments to match.  So when holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> the cube snaps from here:

[image]

To here:

[image]

I would like it to snap to the 1 foot grid, or possibly any other amount I find useful.  It would also be nice to be able to change the rotation snap as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the latest release, the 2.73 release candidate, it seems that when the scene units are set to *imperial* it will snap by feet instead of blender units at all times (when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed).  This holds true even in *perspective* view mode.

But it seems to still be impossible to change the snapping increment to a custom value.

Comment: this is still the case as of 3.3.0. there doesn't seem to be a way to define the increment, no matter the units you're using or the unit scale.

Answer (score 16):

If you hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> while snapping, then it will snap in smaller increments:

[image]

Or if you view from an aligned view such as top ortho (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>), the snapping increments will be equal to the grid subdivisions (which change with zoom level):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer gamdalf3.  So I gather it is impossible to manually change the snap amount to some arbitrary useful amount?  And likewise for the rotation snap?

Comment: @PGmath Not that I know of.. But you can specify the amount to rotate/translate numerically, e.g. `G`+`Z`+`=` `6"` will translate the object 6 inches up on the Z axis.

Comment: Can we conclude that holding shift+ctrl+ snaps to a tenth of the ctrl+ snap?

Comment: @TavernSenses That seems to be how it works, yes. I haven't looked at the internals to be sure though.

Answer (score 12):

Snapping will use the resolution of the displayed grid, so you have to change the scale of that.

You can do that in the Properties Shelf (press <kbd>N</kbd>). Open *Display* rollout and change the scale of the grid. (For example if you use *Metric* system, type `0.01` and Blender will snap things to centimeters).

Comment: So 0.001 will snap to things to millimeters. No, it doesn't. In fact, the display scale appears to have no influence on snapping whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Snap Template made of vertices according to the desired offset in a separate Mesh object, then snap to those with snapping mode set to Vertex.

I would also make one that is spaced one unit apart.
Then for quick edits to this, you could scale it.
If I needed 1/8 I could scale the template down by that factor and use it at those increments, then I could reset it by scaling it back up 8 times.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the scene units, in the properties window. By default blender is in *blender units* which is the same as *meters*, but if you change it to *Imperial* grid snapping will snap to the new imperial grid only if you are in one of the views *front*, *top*, *left*, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Blender snaps to the displayed grid. Changing the scale of the displayed grid is answered at [this other answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13803/how-to-make-the-measuring-grid-larger#answer-13806). The method of doing so changed around blender version 2.7,

Answer (score -1):

Turn on "absolute grid snapping" then go to Scene > Units and adjust the "Unit scale" property. Higher values will make the increments smaller.