# Change spacing when using ctrl to move specific amount of units

Tags: transforms

When I want to move/rotate/scale with a defined spacing or amount of units I use the ctrl key but it moves one whole blender unit, does anyone know how can  I change this spacing so that it moves 0.1 blender units?

Comment: Does [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15847/2217) answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

While moving/rotating/scaling press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to transform by 0.1 of blender unit.
[image]

You may do the same thing as above but without holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button enabling the ***Snapping Tool*** (just click on the *magnet icon* and set the *snap element type* to ***Increment***). Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button while moving/rotating/scaling to transform by 0.1 of blender unit.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel silly it was a pretty simple question. Do you know if I can tweak it so that it is always 0.1 by using only ctrl?

Comment: @Zloy Smiertniy I don't think it is possible using only Ctrl button. BTW please don't feel silly :). Although I use Blender for quite time I often ask a question here and feel like an idiot cause the answer is very simple :).