# Change Unit/Increment Sizes

Tags: python, modeling, units

So I was trying to figure out how one would go about creating some sort of Minecraft based animation. I am accustomed to Blender's workflow, and I was wondering if you could change the snap units (the ones used when holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **AND** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) from 1 grid size and 0.1 grid size to 1 BU (not grid size) and 0.0625 (not grid size and 1/16 because there are 16 pixels in a block in Minecraft, therefore you'd have to move by 1/16 of a unit a lot). I guess an alternative would be changing the grid size to decrease by 1/16ths.

I don't mind having to write a Python script for this. I would assume this would be something that would need a script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the snapping increment in different units?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/how-to-change-the-snapping-increment-in-different-units)

Comment: I am trying to change to exactly and always 1 BU and 1/16 BU. That only explains that the grid units are used and you can zoom in and out. Since the grid units are always 1/10 of the last one, you will never get 1/16.

Comment: What I was actually asking in that question was if it is possible to change the snapping increment.  Basically [the answer is no](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/how-to-change-the-snapping-increment-in-different-units#comment22416_15848).

Comment: I am also asking for a Python solution... If we can be sure that there is no way to implement this using Python not just modifying settings, then I guess there's no way