# How do I measure half the length of a specific part of an object in Blender (3D modeling software)?

Tags: modeling

[image]
[image]

As you can see in my images, all of my cubes are inaccurately placed on this object and the four corned cubes (labeled as blue) are not placed accurately on the on the corners of this object. Is there a way to accurately space out the difference between each cube, for example I might want each cube to be placed 2 cm apart from each other, and I want all the four corned cubes to be placed precisely on the corners of this object?

How would I do this for this particular situation?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/how-to-change-the-snapping-increment-in-different-units Check this out.

Comment: As for snapping to the corners, you can change the snapping mode. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html

Answer (score 1):

Use snap vertex and an array modifier. By snapping a cubes vertex to the outside edge of the castle turret the cube will be lined up. Then add a array modifier to that cube and set the count to 4. If your math is right number 4 cube will line up with the opposed edge.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the way you would do this on the spur of the moment, but it might illustrate a couple of methods you can use in other places as well.

With Pivot set to 3D Cursor, and snap set to target > vertex  and source > median, as shown...

[image]

1. A cube and a frame, (the cube's base at the same Z as the frame, the 3D cursor at the frame's center).
2. Using the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> and constraining it to the center of edges by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, cut a line between 2 mitres.
3. Create the appropriate number of edge loops across that face: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, Scroll the number of loops, and  left then right click to exit without sliding the loops.
4. in object mode, move the cube in XY (<kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>). Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you drag enables snap: move your mouse over the leftmost new vertex on the frame to snap the median of the cube to its XY.
5. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> the cube to copy it (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to make an instance), and  before any other operation, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain the duplicate's movement to XY. As before, snap the duplicate's median to the next vertex along your guideline.
6. Then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> twice, repeats the last action, creaing the next 2 cubes.
7. Now, select all 4 cubes, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> 90, to fill the next side.
8. Lastly select all the cubes. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> 180, to finish. (Delete your guidelines).