# How to make edge length to always be multiple of a certain number?

Tags: modeling, edges

I want to make a model whose edges' length (all of them) are always multiples of a certain number.

Later on I want to apply a pixel-art texture and I need to have a 1:1 relationship between the texture and the model so there is consistency in the size of the pixel across all faces on the model.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are modelling?  For example sake how would the UV sphere be handled, with sides that are trapeziums?

Comment: [This is what I'm currently modeling](https://imgur.com/a/rRX7y4W) using [this tool](https://chemikhazi.itch.io/sprytile) as a first approach. I quickly realized that applying directly this tool has the problem I stated (I think you can notice in the image) so I haven't really thought how a UV sphere would be handled. Maybe I will just try to map it as approximate as possible to make the 'pixel inconsistency' as less noticeable as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [snapping features](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/how-to-change-the-snapping-increment-in-different-units) and align all your vertices to the grid. 
If your edges are not aligned to the grid you can set the edge length in different ways like described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-to-set-a-specific-edge-length-numerically).