# Problem faced while import and export

Tags: export, import

The AutoCAD file when Imported to Blender in .DXF is not workable in terms that when zoomed in does not zoom out. The scale of the imported file is also not clear and all that can be done is change the scale of the Software.  We are trying to work out an architectural building which requires details to be sorted and is very difficult to do as we cant see the whole file.

Comment: it's difficult to give an answer to this, what scale is the DXF? do you have clipping plane set large enough so the viewport can show it ?  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: The DXF from CAD is on scale 1:1 and we are working on the default screen. Kindly enlighten us on clipping plane?

Comment: What is the largest dimension of the building: 10 meters? 100 meters? Please read the answer in the suggested link and determine if if the view-port clipping plane start-end make any difference.

Comment: Also: [why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport?rq=1)

Comment: As a test, try scaling the building down by 100 times before exporting it.  Different packages use different standards for units.  Do you have a Dropbox account that will allow you to upload the model and post a link here?  It would be better if the model is simplified first.  The first thing I'd do is check both the exporter and importer settings for a scale factor.